# Viewing the extents of individual tiles in Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF

Tags: python, extents, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a COG, e.g. https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/52/J/FS/2023/5/S2A_52JFS_20230501_0_L2A/TCI.tif and I want to inspect the internal tiling structure.

How can I view the extent of each of the individual tiles in the COG?

I am comfortable with Python, QGIS, Typescript etc.

Comment: Are you comfortable with GDAL in python?  You can https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Open then from the dataset, make a layer object https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Dataset.GetLayerByIndex then from the layer GetExtent https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Dataset.GetLayerByIndex to get an array of float with the xMin,xMax,yMin and yMax. If you want to do this in bulk you could try creating a VRT file with GDALbuildVRT https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html ; a VRT is an XML so you could get individual extens using XML reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to find out the internal tiling structure i.e the blocks, you can use GDAL or rasterio commandline tools:

```
gdalinfo /vsicurl/https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/52/J/FS/2023/5/S2A_52JFS_20230501_0_L2A/TCI.tif

<snip...>
Band 1 Block=1024x1024
<snip...>

rio info https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/52/J/FS/2023/5/S2A_52JFS_20230501_0_L2A/TCI.tif

{"blockxsize": 1024, "blockysize": 1024, <snip...>
```

If you want to visualise the blocks, you can use [`rasterio.DatasetReader.block_windows`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.block_windows) to access block window offsets and [`rasterio.windows.bounds`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.bounds) to convert the windows to coordinates. Then make geometry from them if you wish, e.g.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.windows import bounds
from shapely.geometry import box


tif = r"https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/52/J/FS/2023/5/S2A_52JFS_20230501_0_L2A/TCI.tif"

with rio.open(tif) as src:
    features = {"id": [], "geometry": []}
    for id, (block_index, window) in enumerate(src.block_windows(1)):
        features["id"].append(id)
        features["geometry"].append(box(*bounds(window, src.transform)))

    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(features, crs=src.crs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a single tile. so all you need to do is use gdal to get extent:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

data = gdal.Open(
'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/52/J/FS/2023/5/S2A_52JFS_20230501_0_L2A/TCI.tif',
GA_ReadOnly
)

geoTransform = data.GetGeoTransform()
minx = geoTransform[0]
maxy = geoTransform[3]
maxx = minx + geoTransform[1] * data.RasterXSize
miny = maxy + geoTransform[5] * data.RasterYSize
print(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
data = None
```

Comment: Hi @B-C B. what do you mean its a single tile? Do you mean my example dataset is not tiled internally?

Comment: Hi, 
the tile name is in the file name: 52JFS.
these tiles are 110km by 110km, just like the one you have there. 
I've never heard of internal tiles from these tiles.

Comment: I think that refers to the sentinel tile. TIFFs are often tiled internally, and COGs make extra use of this.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know that. Thanks

Comment: Thats OK! Thanks for your help too